# My application crashed when snapped with items in listviews

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows

So, im currently working on a project using C#/XAML for a Windows 8 Store App and I've encountred a problem.

When the user navigates to a Page a ListView with some Controls shows up.
Then when the user decides to snap the page my application crashes and shows this:

[image]

In my IntelliTrace this shows up and I press an Exception.

[image]

It navigates me to this code.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>

    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

    public EmployeeAssisterClient() : 
            base(EmployeeAssisterClient.GetDefaultBinding(), EmployeeAssisterClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress()) {
        this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.TimeLoggerEndPoint.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
```

I add the controls to the listview as follows:

```
            _timeReports = _timeReportDatabase.GetAll();

            foreach (var timeReport in _timeReports)
            {
                _invoicedControls.Add(new InvoicedControl(timeReport)
                    {
                        Customer = timeReport.CustomerName,
                        Date = timeReport.Date,
                        WorkedTime = timeReport.WorkedTime.ToString(),
                        InvoicedTime = timeReport.InvoicedTime.ToString()
                    });
            }

            TimeReportsListViewFillView.ItemsSource = _invoicedControls;
            TimeReportsListViewFullView.ItemsSource = _invoicedControls;
            TimeReportsListViewPortraitView.ItemsSource = _invoicedControls;
            TimeReportsListViewSnappedView.ItemsSource = _invoicedControls;
```

EDIT==============================================================================

This is the error wich is thrown

[image]

I turned off WCF debugging by typing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VsDiag_regwcf.exe -u" into the Cmd and it resolved 2/3 problems

This is the last error in my IntelliTrace: 
[image]

What does this error mean? And does any1 have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please see "Locals" pane in Visual studio 2012, you'll notice a value called $exception. What's the value of it. See this [screen shot](http://prntscr.com/132rpk)

Comment: This is how my Locals look like when the app crashes: http://oi42.tinypic.com/35nacko.jpg

Comment: It's `ArgumentException` throwing.

Comment: Where shall I catch the ArgumentException? on the NavigateTo?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shown, it's likely that you've used a generated page (from a template), then removed some of the Xaml inside of it, which is fine.

The thing that you likely haven't done is removed the references to those controls you removed from the storyboards of the VisualStateManager, specifically for the Snapped state.

Go to your page and check (generally at the bottom of) the Xaml for the "Snapped" VisualState, then check and see if any of the Storyboards have a TargetName of a control that you no longer have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've used the basic page wich generates a backButton and a pageTitle for me. But when I removed those from the page I did also remove them from my StoryBoard. (My StoryBoard only contains 4 TargetNames: "FullView, SnappedView, FillView and PortraitView" (And I've got those StoryBoard in each of my 4 VisualStates).